# API to get android google play ratings(include daily rating)

Tags: android, google-play

If there is the API to get the rating of my App, including the overview rating and daily average rating, like below:

[image]

I searched in [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher), not found related api

Comment: My strange method : You can parse score div html from your application market page.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no internal API for that. But you can use 3rd party solutions with some prices: https://42matters.com/docs/app-market-data/android/apps/ranks